# Prove Edited Algorithm of Bellman–Ford?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, correctness-proof, weighted-graphs

**Please Note:** I forgot a small detail which caused the algorithm to be incorrect, please read the new version and thanks for pointing that.

---

I am stuck on this question for a week and hope to get some help:

Algorithm:

> Given 2 sided Graph ie bipartite graph *G(L,R,E)*, a weight function and a root vertex *s*:
>
> 1. Define *E1* as the group of edges connecting vertex from *L* to *R*
>    (the rest are in *E2* Group).
> 2. For each vertex *v*, let
>    *d(v) = ∞* except *d(s) = 0*
> 3. Do *(|L|+|R|)/2* (round floor)
>    iterations of the following:
>
> Check **Every** edge in the graph, while finishing all edges > in *E1* **and only then** moving on to *E2*: if *d(v)>d(u)+w(u,v)* then let
> *d(v)=d(u)+w(u,v)*
>
> Prove that if there is no circular path with total negative weight in
> *G*, then the given algorithm returns for each vertex *v* the minimal
> weight of a path from *s* to *v*.

---

My try:

- For every vertex *v* we can conclude that there is a shortest path from *s* which is simple (no vertex appears twice, else we are getting a contradiction to the fact that there is no negative circular paths)
- The difference between number of edges from E1 and E2 is no more than 1
- For every simple and short path *P* there is no more than *(|L|+|R|)/2* (round floor) edges from *E1* (and the same for *E2*).

Claim: For every vertex *v* if there is a shortest path $P$ from *s* to *v* , which contains $k$ edges from $E1$ then at the end of *k*-th iteration *d(v)=|P|* ie the algorithm's calculation is correct.

Proof: By induction on *k*.

---

But as I progressed it seemed that the claim doesn't cover all cases (Thus it's wrong). For example, it worked when *v*  is in *R* group but failed To help prove the case when *v*  is in *L* group.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Any help please on what should the claim be? (as mine is wrong or isn't helpful to prove correctness)

Comment: Prove by induction on the number of iterations that at the end of iteration $i$ all values $d(u)$ where $u$ is at distance at most $2i$ from $s$ are exactly the distance from $s$ to $u$ in $G$.

Comment: Another, less precise, way to show the result is noticing that each iteration of your algorithm corresponds to two iterations of the Bellman-Ford algorithm. Since the correctness of the Bellman-Ford algorithm does not depend on the order in which edges are examined (which can be different between iterations) we are free to choose our own edge order.

Comment: In details, an iteration of your algorithm yields the same distances obtained by performing 1) an iteration of Bellman-Ford in which edges in $E_2$ are examined before those in $E_1$ (here no distance is updated while examining $E_2$), and 2) and iteration of Bellman-Ford in which edges in $E_1$ are examined before those in $E_2$ (no distance is actually updated while examining $E_1$).

Comment: @Steven I tried induction and that's where I stuck, I said let P be the shortest path from u to v of lengh n, ie P: u->...->w->v. I said let's look at u->...->w which is of length n-1 so according to the assumption we know that d(w)=s(u,w). But how this can help me say that d(v)=s(u,v)? I proved that at every moment s(s,v)<=d(v) if that helps. Thanks

Comment: Plus I showed that d(w)+w(w,v)=s(s,w)+w(w,v) (used the assumption here) = s(u,v) But I am looking to connect d(v) with d(w)+w(w,v) in some how (If I can show it's smaller then I finished). please help me

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D(t,i)$ denote the length of the shortest among the path from $s$ to $t$ in $G$ that use at most $i$ edges.

We will focus on the generic $i$-th iteration of the algorithm and show that:

- (i) after all the edges in $E_1$ have been considered, we must have $d(t) \le D(t, 2i)$ for each vertex $t \in R$.
- (ii) after all the edges in $E_2$ have been considered, we must have $d(t) \le D(t, 2i)$ for each vertex $t \in L$.

As an edge case we consider the $0$-th iteration to be completed immediately before the start of the for loop.

The proof is by induction on $i$. The base case $i=0$ is trivially true since the only vertex at hop-distance $0$ from $s$ is $s \in L$ itself and the algorithm explicitly sets $d(s) = 0 = D(s, 0)$.

Consider now $i > 0$. If $t=s$ we know, by induction hypothesis, that after iteration $0$ we have $d(s) \le D(s,0) \le D(s, 2i)$.
Therefore, we restrict ourselves to the case in which $t \neq $ s and $D(t, 2i)$ is finite.
Let $(v,t)$ be the last edge in any shortest path from $s$ to $t$ in $G$ that uses at most $2i$ edges.

If $t \in R$ then $v \in L$ and all paths to $v$ have even hop-length. Therefore, when $(v,t) \in E_1$ is considered, we have $d(v) \le D(v, 2(i-1))$ by induction hypothesis and hence:
$$
D(t, 2i) = D(v, 2i-1) + w(v,t) =  D(v, 2(i-1)) + w(v,t) \ge d(v)+w(t).
$$
This ensures that, after examining $(v,t)$ in iteration $i$ we must have $d(t) \le d(v)+w(t) \le D(t, 2i)$ and proves (i).

If $t \in L$ then $v \in R$ and all paths to $v$ have odd hop-length. When $(v,t) \in E_2$ is considered we have $d(v) \le D(v, 2i)$ (this follows from (i), which we just proved). Therefore:
$$
D(t, 2i) = D(v, 2i-1) + w(v,t) = D(v, 2i) + w(v,t) \ge d(v) + w(v,t).
$$
Therefore, after $(v,t)$ is examined, we must have $d(t) \le D(t, 2i)$. This proves (ii) and concludes the proof by induction.

At this point we just need to notice that, the above claim, implies that at the end of the algorithm $d(t)$ is at most $D(t, 2 \lfloor (|L|+|R|)/2\rfloor) \le D(t, |L|+|R|-1)$, where $D(t, |L|+|R|-1)$ is exactly  the distance from $s$ to $t$ in $G$. Moreover, all (finite) distances $d(t)$ computed by the algorithm correspond to the length of an actual path to $t$ in $G$, showing that $d(t)$ is also not smaller than the distance from $s$ to $t$ in $G$.

---

**This part of the answer refers to a previous version of the question in which the Algotithm did not prescribe any particular order in which to consider the edges**

If by 2-sided graph you mean bipartite graph, then the algorithm is wrong.

As a counterexample consider the graph $G=(L \cup R, E)$ where $L = \{s, \ell\}$, $R =\{r\}$ $E=\{(s,r), (r, \ell)\}$, and all edge weights are $1$. The algorithm will perform $\left\lfloor \frac{|L|+|R|}{2} \right\rfloor = 1$ iteration. Since there is no prescribed order in which the edges are considered, we can look at the case in which $(r, \ell)$ is considered before $(s, \ell)$.

When  $(r, \ell)$ is examined, the condition of the if statement is not satisfied, so $d(\ell)$ is not updated. Moreover, when $(s, r)$ is considered only $d(r)$ can possibly be updated, so $d(\ell)$ is unchanged.

This shows that at the end of the algorithm $d(\ell) = + \infty$ but the distance between $s$ and $\ell$ in $G$ is $2$.

Comment: So sorry my fault, the actual question said to run E1 before E2 and I ignored that by mistake. Please keep this as it's helpful and hope if you can help me fix my proof and continue it.